# How to fix "Received fatal alert: handshake_failure" error when installing Erlide in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, erlang, erlide

I've just installed Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers, version 2019-06 (4.12.0) and am trying to add the Erlide plugin.

There are two ways to go about it:
Help -> Install New Software. Following instructions on the site https://erlide.org/articles/eclipse/120_Installing-and-updating.html#update_sites, I put "https://download.erlide.org/update" as URL.

... or ...

I try to install it through the Eclipse Marketplace: 
Help -> Eclipse Marketplace. Here I search for "Erlide" and the choose "install".

In both cases it comes down to the same error:

Unable to read repository at
http://download.erlide.org/update/compositeContent.xml.
Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

I would like to ask for help regarding this matter.

Thank you,
Rui

Comment: The update site URL of the Erlide Eclipse Marketplace entry is HTTP while in the instructions the HTTP**S** URL is given. So in the first case the error message is _"...at https://..."_, isn't it? Does deactivating or removing the HTTP update site in _Window > Preferences: Install/Update > Available Update Sites_ fix your issue? Are you behind a proxy? Do other HTTPS update site URLs work?

Comment: Hi. You're absolutely right. The error message shows HTTPS in one case and HTTP in another. Deactivating/Removing the HTTP update site won't fix my issue. I am not behind a proxy. I don not have other HTTPS update site URL's. Only HTTP.

Comment: What happen if in _Help > Install New Software..._ you work with e.g. [`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/`](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/)? With which Java do you run Eclipse (this might caused by an older Java 8 or 9 OpenJDK)?

Comment: I didn't really understand how the URL you gave me (https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/) can help. Am I supposed to choose all items and install them so that afterward I try to install the Erlide plugin? I run Eclipse with Java 8 Update 121 (build 1.8.0_121-b13).

Comment: If you enter an HTTPS update site URL in the _Work with_ field and items with checkboxes are shown below, it means HTTPS works in general. Is this the Java 8 Oracle or the Java 8 OpenJDK JRE/JDK? Please double check if you really run Eclipse with Java 8 Update 121 in _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details: Cofigurations_. The system library provides the HTTPS implementation and throws the `handshake_failure`, so this is likely a problem of the Java VM used to run Eclipse. But it might also an issue of the server providing the Erlide update site.

Comment: HTTPS works in general. Using "Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details: Cofigurations" it tells me this: "eclipse.vm=C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin\server\jvm.dll". I'm leaning towards problems with the server providing the Erlide update.

Comment: In the meantime, I updated to Java 8 Update 221 (build 1.8.0_221-b11)

Comment: I also removed the Eclipse installation I had and installed a new Eclipse (for java script and web developers). It all works fine now! I really want to thank you @howlger for sticking with me during this ordeal. It means a lot to me, thank you.

Comment: Great that everything works now. I guess upgrading Java 8 to Update 161 or higher has fixed the issue (see my edited answer below).

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. See [Erlide issue #328](https://github.com/erlang/erlide_eclipse/issues/328), [comment by villiros](https://github.com/erlang/erlide_eclipse/issues/328#issuecomment-501902864):

> I run into the same problem. Turned out that the cypher suites
>   required by the server were not allowed by the Java installation
>   because of export control stuff.
>
> The solution for me was to install the [JCE Unlimited Strength Policy](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html).

**Upgrading Java 8 to Update 161 or higher** might also be a solution, since in this update support for the TLS session hash and extended master secret extension (RFC 7627) in the JDK JSSE provider has been added (see [JDK 8u161 Update Release Notes, section *Added TLS session hash and extended master secret extension support*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u161-relnotes-4021379.html#JDK-8148421)).